# How can I tell if a process is not running?

Tags: vb.net, explorer

Alright so I've been stuck on this one for 2 days going on 3 and I still can't figure out a way. I need to use this to tell if explorer is running if not start it, the reason I need to do this is to make a program to prevent people from leaking files... Got the rest of the code sorted out just stuck on this one. The only way I can think of which isn't efficient is to add all the processes into a listbox and search for explorer and if it's not there then start explorer. Huge thanks for the help :)

Comment: That's some impressive XY problem you got there. What does Explorer running have to do with leaking files? Is this a security problem or a performance one?

Comment: Had a friend help me out on this one, just ended up doing it a different way. I want to kill explorer while the file is open so you can browse for the file the upload it some were... It's for security.

Comment: I don't understand what you're getting at there. You're trying to close explorer while the file is open so you (the program? the user? some other user?) can browse (search for?) a file that was (is about to be?) uploaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim sExplorerName As String = "explorer"
Dim oProcessList() As Process
Dim bFound As Boolean = False

' Get a list of all running processes

oProcessList = Process.GetProcesses()

' Check each process to see if it is explorer

For Each oProc As Process In oProcessList
    If (sExplorerName = oProc.ProcessName) Then
        ' We found the explorer process
        bFound = True
    End If
Next oProc

If bFound = False Then
    ' Start explorer.exe since it was not found to be running
    Process.Start(System.IO.Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("windir"), "explorer.exe"))
End If
```